# how can I input and display the data via the database quickly?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, html, visual-web-developer

I have a webpage in which users input some data and that data is supposed to be stored in the database and then at the same moment should be displayed in the display section.

I have a very trivial question please. How can I take the result from the database to be displayed the same moment the user inputs it in the database? Is it like something cronjob, which checks the database every second that the new results have been input or not?

e.g. I have a registration form to register the properties in a property webpage. if a user submits a form to my database, how can I keep checking whether the database is updated or not? The users would expect their property listing to be displayed on the webpage within a second

Comment: This question is very broad... There are a variety of ways you can go about this. Each with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: i don't think you should use the database to do this ! use javascript or any program lang and store the result in the database at the end of your session

Comment: e.g. I have a registration form to register the properties in a property webpage. if a user submits a form to my database, how can I keep checking whether the database is updated or not? The users would expect their property listing to be displayed on the webpage within a second

Comment: Why not use a query to simply get a user's latest inserted property instead?